# How to calculate the time for two or more category for datetime column in dataframe

Tags: sql, pandas, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

I have a dataframe which consist of datetime, class columns. The class column has values as 'open', 'close'. This is an IOT data. I have to calculate the total open time and also total closed time. The dataframe is something as-

```
index   datetime                    class
------------------------------------------
0      2020-10-05 08:55:00.161326   open
1      2020-10-05 09:00:00.137587   close
2      2020-10-05 09:05:00.089382   close
3      2020-10-05 09:10:00.219278   close
4      2020-10-05 09:15:00.160964   close
5      2020-10-06 09:20:00.315548   close
6      2020-10-06 09:25:00.080932   open
7      2020-10-06 09:30:00.335536   open
8      2020-10-06 09:35:00.202047   close
9      2020-10-06 09:45:00.242022   open
```

The response that I need to get is as-

```
index   day_count   hour_count          class
-----------------------------------------------
0              0    0:15:00.097376      open
1              1    23:59:59.918860     close
```

Basically I am trying to capture the runtime of the sensor using data. If possible I am also looking for solution in postgresql. I prefer postgresql over dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Postgres solution could look like this:

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3e5820e3fba24b8bf9304a1ffa65ffab)

```
SELECT
    class,
    SUM(duration)                                                         -- 5
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        lead(datetime) OVER (ORDER BY datetime) - datetime as duration    -- 4
    FROM (
        SELECT
            *,
            COALESCE(                                                     -- 2
                (class != lag(class) OVER (ORDER BY datetime))::int,      -- 1
                 1
            ) as state
        FROM 
            t
    ) s
    WHERE state != 0                                                      -- 3
) s
GROUP BY class
```

1. `lag()` shifts the current `class` value to the next row. These two values can be compared. If they equal, then the result is `0`, else `1`
2. `COALESCE` is just for the very first record, which, of course, does not hold a previous value
3. All values with `value = 0` (intermediate steps) are removed
4. Afterwards, the `lead()` value copys the next datetime value to the current row. So, the difference between the next and the current `datetime` value can be calculated. Now, we know the difference from one `class` value change to another.
5. Final: Group by `class` and sum the durations.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use window functions and aggregation:

```
select class, sum(lead_datetime - datetime) as duration
from (
    select t.*, lead(datetime) over(order by datetime) lead_datetime
    from mytable t
) t
group by class
```

For each row, this computes the delta duration until the next row, that is then associated to the `class` of the current row. There is no need to skip the intermediate steps, you can just sum the durations together.